# Apending text to end of file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am using sed to add text to end of file. So far I have tried

a. `sed -i -e '$ a mynewtext' filename`

b. `sed -e '$amynewtext' filename`

My file looks like this

```
90577958

90399451

90219954

90089937

90994000

90083995

90349994

90133537
```

After running both a) and b) I get a new line with `mynewtext`. It does not append after `90133537` like `90133537mynewtext`.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

That's just what the `a` (append) command does.

If you want to place the text at the end of the last line you can use the `s` (substitute) command instead ex.

```
$s/$/mynewtext/
```

The first `$` addresses the last line, while the second `$` anchors the substitution to its end.

Comment: I'd just add that that use of `a` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Just beware that `mynewtext` can't contain `&`, or `\1`, or `/` or newlines. If you need it to be able to contain any chars then you need a different solution.